# Можно ли запустить приложение из оперативной памяти?

Tags: c#

Например наше приложение должно извлекать другое приложение из ресурсов и запускать его. Но что бы не распаковывать его на диск запускать напрямую из оперативной памяти.

Comment: Да. Возможно, не каждое приложение, но точно можно.

Comment: Теоретически да, но на практике этому могут помешать некоторые вещи, например [DEP](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Предотвращение_выполнения_данных).

Comment: Вам нужно запустить приложение на .NET или обычное?

Comment: [Вот тут](https://stackoverflow.com/a/305319/276994) о запуске обычного приложения.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Да, можно. В свое время задавался этой целью, но затем понял, что овчинка выделки всё же не стоит и стал пользоваться виртуальным диском.
Консольное проще, насколько я понимаю. Другое дело, вы должны знать о программе хотя бы "кое-что". Вот тут [успешный вариант запуска](http://www.cyberforum.ru/csharp-net/thread1548194.html)

Но вообще готовьтесь "лопатить" MSDN по таким запросам, как "PE/COFF format",
"MapViewOfFile", "PE relocation" и т.п.

Comment: MapViewOfFile совершенно не обязателен, а при чем тут COFF - вообще не понятно...

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов Ок, слегка некорректен: PE/COFF

Comment: Его лучше вообще MZPE называть :-)

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов Мой локальный MSDN выдает по COFF 432 статьи, по PE/COFF 112, по MZPE - всего 4 :)

Comment: @ViktorTomilov: Вариант по вашей ссылке запускает лишь .NET-сборки.